# Adding / Subtracting Two Fields in Query Criteria

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table that contains Suburbs and their Geocodes.

I have a query that returns the selected suburb from a form, together with all other suburbs within a +0.5 and -0.5 long and lat.

The Criteria in the query, for the Long and Lat fields respectively are;

> Between [Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Long]-0.5 And
>   [Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Long]+0.5
>
> Between [Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Lat]-0.5 And
>   [Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Lat]+0.5

This works perfectly. What I have been trying to do is change the '0.5' from a static value to a reference to a combo box on the form (giving the option of 0.01, 0.05, 0.5 etc). I've tried the below and various other combinations of brackets etc but it doesn't seem to work.

> Between
>   [Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Lat]-[Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![cmbSubDistance]
>   And
>   [Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Lat]+[Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![cmbSubDistance]

I put a textbox on the form and referenced it to the combo, and it seems to pick up the value fine. So it seems to be something with the way I'm adding and subtracting the two references?

On another note, I'm obviously using a very simple method of finding nearby suburbs. I know that while latitude to distance remain pretty constant, long varies - this is just for Victoria Australia, so are there any disadvantages of doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! It all came down to encasing the second statement (which refers to the distance - the '0.5') with the Val function. I'm not completely sure why this works, but it does.

So now my SQL looks like;

```
SELECT tblStatePostCodeLongLat.Suburb, tblStatePostCodeLongLat.StateCode, tblStatePostCodeLongLat.Long, tblStatePostCodeLongLat.Lat, tblStatePostCodeLongLat.Accuracy
FROM tblStatePostCodeLongLat
WHERE (((tblStatePostCodeLongLat.StateCode)="VIC") AND ((tblStatePostCodeLongLat.Long) Between ([Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Long]-Val([Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![txtNearSubDistance])) And ([Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Long]+Val([forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![txtNearSubDistance]))) AND ((tblStatePostCodeLongLat.Lat) Between ([Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Lat]-Val([forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![txtNearSubDistance])) And ([Forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![Lat]+Val([forms]![frmFindMeetingLocations]![txtNearSubDistance]))))
ORDER BY tblStatePostCodeLongLat.Suburb;
```

Thank God for that - I was going loopy! Hope the solution helps someone.

Cheers

Red